# How do I rename sites I am following?

Tags: sharepoint-online

On my SharePoint homepage, under 'Following' in the left hand list pane, all the sites I am following are called 'Home'. This is making SharePoint hard to navigate. Does anyone know if I can change this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no option to rename the site title from your SharePoint Homepage, you need to login each site and got to site setting -> Under look and feel -> choose title and change the name over there and it will reflect in your homepage

Or you can choose the below option to add all those team site which makes you to get confuse

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. None of my SharePoint sites are called 'Home', all have unique titles when I check through 'Look and Feel'. Yet they all appear titled 'Home' on my dashboard.

I do not have overall permissions to change the Featured links.

Comment: Then i believe you have clicked follow button when the site title was as 'Home' and You can add or edit the Featured link as you should have full permission for that page